# Why are (Qt) menus misplaced on some screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce, qt

Using XFCE4 on 18.04 together with Qt applications has strange effects on different monitors: I have two extra monitors attached to my laptop. When I move a Qt application (qpdfview and quassel tried) to one of the extra monitors, the dropdown menu is misplaced as can be seen in the image below.

The displacement seems to be the same as the laptop monitor's vertical position is displaced downward with xrandr to align with the physical setup. If I move the window up and down, the menu always appears at the same position until I move it past the menu position. Then the menu appears a the right place.

If I move the window to the laptop's own screen, the menu appears in the right place.

Firefox, Thunderbird and other programs don't have this problem.

Any idea how to fix this? Some xrandr special option?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I don't know the answer yet, but I'm experiencing a similar problem with `pavucontrol` (which is a GTK app) running in Sway. For me, the context menu is misplaced to the right by the horizontal resolution of a secondary monitor that is placed to the left.